# Uploading files to storage. Multiple users

Tags: python, cloud, storage

I am making an application in python.

In short:
The user inputs some images for calibration, and some images that then are transformed by algorithm.

To further improve the algorithm and service, I want the users to upload calibration images to a central storage in the cloud. How would I go about this?

How do I make it secure(I.e. Not get people randomly upload terabytes of files)?

Is it possible to have a script on the server/cloud side that validates if the uploaded file should be deleted or not?

I have some experience with Azure, but open for anything..

Comment: The question is uncleared. what type of application you are developing with python? Is that a desktop application with GUI vs Commandline or api service or web application?! And what's the skill level of your user etc are also important for providing any possible solution

Comment: Its an executable with a simple GUI. Maybe desktop application, but most likely it will be called by a Adobe Lightroom as an external plugin. The application is then  executed by a lua script.


Will maybe also release scripts if possible(but this is not important atm)

Answer (score 1):

A high level perspective:

1. develop a middleware to manage user authentication and proxy the upload to any cloud storage on your own. In python you may want to look for web API framework like Django / Flask to implement user authentication with a database properly. You also have to implement secure connection between the middleware and client.
2. A less recommended implementation is calling cloud service API directly from client, for example AWS provides a boto python client which can access to S3 API with accessKey(AK) and secretKey(SK) of a IAM user. You could prompt the user for their AK and SK for uploading file on S3. Then you are relying on the authorization of AWS. However this would expose your public cloud account to user, in security measure each user using your application would need to create a unique IAM user, setting up with minimal access policy properly. If you have lot of users, you will need to consider a user group for your application to minimize your effort on user management.